# View failures when building with xcodebuild

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, clang, xcodebuild

We are building multiple targets with `xcodebuild`, but from the command line, all we get is failures like so:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC MOAIFmodExChannel.o ../../src/moaiext-fmod-ex/MOAIFmodExChannel.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

If we run the builds in Xcode, it tells me information about why the build failed. How can we view this from the command line? Is there a log file where this would get dumped or can we provide some kind of flag to `xcodebuild` to enable that?

Comment: nice downvote with no comment. sorry if this is a poor question because I've never compiled from the command line before. inexperience doesn't mean the question isn't valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcodebuild` outputs a summary at the end of the build that mentions which commands failed. That's what you quoted in your answer. The actual error message will be visible in the output at the point those commands ran. You can scroll up in the output until you find an earlier occurrence of each command (e.g., `CompileC MOAIFmodExChannel.o …`) to see the error messages.